# Getting the first video track multiple time while trying to combine three different video tracks in same frame using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to combine multiple videos and their audio in one video frame for that I am using **AVFoundation** framework.

For that I have created a method which accepts array of asset and as of now I am passing three different video's asset.

So far I have combined their audio but problem is with video frame in which **only first asset's video is repeating in every frame**.

[image: Current output video]

I am using below code to combine videos which combine all three video's audio perfectly but first video in input array is repeating three times which is the main issue:

I want all three different video in frames.

```
func merge(Videos aArrAssets: [AVAsset]){

        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        func setup(asset aAsset: AVAsset, WithComposition aComposition: AVMutableComposition) -> AVAssetTrack{

            let aMutableCompositionVideoTrack = aComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
            let aMutableCompositionAudioTrack = aComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

            let aVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
            let aAudioAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0]

            do{
            try aMutableCompositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: aAsset.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: .zero)
            try aMutableCompositionAudioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: aAsset.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: .zero)
            }catch{}

            return aVideoAssetTrack
        }

        let aArrVideoTracks = aArrAssets.map { setup(asset: $0, WithComposition: mixComposition) }

        var aArrLayerInstructions : [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction] = []

        //Transform every video
        var aNewHeight : CGFloat = 0
        for (aIndex,aTrack) in aArrVideoTracks.enumerated(){

            aNewHeight += aIndex > 0 ? aArrVideoTracks[aIndex - 1].naturalSize.height : 0

            let aLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: aTrack)
            let aFristTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: aNewHeight)

            aLayerInstruction.setTransform(aFristTransform, at: .zero)
            aArrLayerInstructions.append(aLayerInstruction)
        }


        let aTotalTime = aArrVideoTracks.map { $0.timeRange.duration }.max()

        let aInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        aInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: aTotalTime!)
        aInstruction.layerInstructions = aArrLayerInstructions

        let aVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        aVideoComposition.instructions = [aInstruction]
        aVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)

        let aTotalWidth = aArrVideoTracks.map { $0.naturalSize.width }.max()!
        let aTotalHeight = aArrVideoTracks.map { $0.naturalSize.height }.reduce(0){ $0 + $1 }
        aVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: aTotalWidth, height: aTotalHeight)


        saveVideo(WithAsset: mixComposition, videoComp : aVideoComposition) { (aError, aUrl) in
            print("Location : \(String(describing: aUrl))")
        }
    }

    private func saveVideo(WithAsset aAsset : AVAsset, videoComp : AVVideoComposition, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ url: URL?) -> Void){


        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy_HHmm"
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)

        // Exporting
        let savePathUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/newVideo_\(date).mov")
        do { // delete old video
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: savePathUrl)
        } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }


        let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: aAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)!
        assetExport.outputFileType = .mov
        assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
//        assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp

        assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
            switch assetExport.status {
            case .completed:
                print("success")
                completion(nil, savePathUrl)
            case .failed:
                print("failed \(assetExport.error?.localizedDescription ?? "error nil")")
                completion(assetExport.error, nil)
            case .cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(assetExport.error?.localizedDescription ?? "error nil")")
                completion(assetExport.error, nil)
            default:
                print("complete")
                completion(assetExport.error, nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I am doing something wrong in code but couldn't figure out where so I need some help to find it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that when you're constructing your `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` the `aTrack` reference is a reference to the track of the original asset which your are setting with

```
let aVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
```

It's trackID is `1`, because it is the first track in it's source `AVAsset`. Accordingly, when you inspect your `aArrLayerInstructions` you will see that the trackIDs of your instructions are all `1`. Which is why you're getting the first video three times

```
(lldb) p aArrLayerInstructions[0].trackID
(CMPersistentTrackID) $R8 = 1
(lldb) p aArrLayerInstructions[1].trackID
(CMPersistentTrackID) $R10 = 1
...
```

The solution is not to enumerate your source tracks but the tracks of your composition when constructing the composition layer instructions.

```
let tracks = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: .video)
for (aIndex,aTrack) in tracks.enumerated(){
...
```

If you do it like that you will get the correct trackIDs for your layer instructions

```
(lldb) p aArrLayerInstructions[0].trackID
(CMPersistentTrackID) $R2 = 1
(lldb) p aArrLayerInstructions[1].trackID
(CMPersistentTrackID) $R4 = 3
...
```